# how to use regex in nokogiri xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, html-parsing, nokogiri

```
div class="ydpbfddd73dsignature" >......
```

How do I use xpath to get whatever text comes after this tag?

I tried doing this

```
nokogiri_html=Nokogiri::HTML html
nokogiri_html.xpath('//div[@class="/.*signature/"]')
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: How about using css selector : `nokogiri_html.css('div[class$="signature"]')` ?

Comment: I don't think that regex does what you intend. Maybe /signature$/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply below XPath:

```
//div[substring(@class, string-length(@class) - 8)="signature"]
```

which means *return div node which has `"signature"` as last 9 characters of class name*

Comment: Worked ! Thanks. Can you specify why its -8 and not -9? what does the 8 specify? index from 0 to 8?

Comment: Because we should get the index of character from which to start counting. String length of class name is `20`, the index of `s` is `12`, so to get `8` we should do `20 - 12 = 8`. I hope it's clear. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: if i want to add a condition where i want to exclude the conditions when class=".......outlooksignature"?  i dont want my xpath function to pick up this case alone.

Comment: `//div[substring(@class, string-length(@class) - 8)="signature" and not(contains(@class, "outlooksignature"))]`